# Elasticsearch shard allocation isn't working after a node shuts down

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-analysis

I setup an ES 6.8.6 cluster with 4 nodes: 2 master/data, 1 master, 1 data. 2 nodes are in same network and the other two in a different network (connectivity is working between all nodes). I generate some indices in order to test replication when a node is off

When I shut down the node where the index is created a see this message in the logs:

> scheduling reroute for delayed shards in [59.6]s

But after a couple of minutes, the index stays UNASSINGED/red. The shards are 47 mb size and cluster.routing.allocation.enable has a value of all. A swell I restart the nodes and even reallocating the index to another node, but nothing happens.

I’d want to know the root cause of this behaviour.

Comment: What happens if you run `POST _cluster/reroute?retry_failed` ?

Comment: I past the result in this pastebin, it means that the allocation failed?

https://pastebin.com/4EN1nrFn

Comment: ES tried 5 times and then stopped retrying. But you can retry manually with the command I gave above.

Comment: Like this? POST _cluster/reroute?retry and where it says that the ES tried 5 time to reallocate?

Comment: I executed the command 5 times, but the shards are not assigned at all.

Comment: Can you provide the result ou get from `GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_yes_decisions=true&include_disk_info=true`

Comment: This is the ouput of the last command: https://pastebin.com/w3V8Ny8y

Comment: Thanks, can you also provide the response from `GET _cat/shards?v` please?

Comment: Sure, here it is https://imgur.com/lL3FZ5K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two data nodes and your index has two replicas in addition to the primary shard (so three copies of the same shard). One shard cannot be allocated to a node that already contains the same shard and that's what the error below tells you from the `GET _cluster/allocation/explain` call:

```
    {
      "decider": "same_shard",
      "decision": "NO",
      "explanation": "the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists [[liferay-20099][0], node[i_Q5sVuES0iRhwNSn4LR3w], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=d4bpWi5rQA6OxfeAdywqrg]]"
    },
```

You can resolve the situation in two ways:

A. You can add a new node (since that's what caused the issue when you shut down your other node) and then when the third node is up re-run `POST _cluster/reroute?retry_failed`.

B. Or you can simply remove one replica for your indexes by running the following command

```
PUT liferay-*/_settings
{
  "index.number_of_replicas": 1
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. However, the message of "scheduling reroute for delayed shards" shows when I have 0 replicas (here are their settings): imgur.com/RwGvMX4 imgur.com/9Lb2Nql And the result of the allocation/explain after I shut down the node of the primary shard and wait for 1 min for allocation: pastebin.com/yByLVfpt I think the explanation is pretty clear, but a second opinion would help

Comment: `cannot allocate because a previous copy of the primary shard existed but can no longer be found on the nodes in the cluster` means that there's no copy of the primary shard anymore... your cluster must be red by now

Comment: Based on the output you've shown earlier, it's pretty clear that you have one too many replicas and that's why two replicas cannot be assigned to any node

Comment: That's right, 2 replicas for 4 nodes only is not enough. And having 0 replicas of all shards means no-balancing and no-fault tolerance. Correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: No what I meant is that 2 replicas + 1 primary (= 3 shards) on two nodes is one too many shard and you need to either remove one replica or add one node. It's perfectly ok to have less shards than nodes, but not the other way because some will not be assignable.

Comment: Hi Val. I applied a new shard config (1 primary 1 replica) and now the allocation is working well. Thanks a lot!